# How to engage in the scientific committee of a conference?

Tags: conference, program-committee

I have published few papers with high impact factors in power systems already and graduated with M.Sc. couple of years ago. I am a reviewer in couple of top journals like IEEE as well.

I thought it would be exciting to enroll in scientific committee of a conference in my field, electrical eng. power systems, specially abroad. Well my question is:

- How can I find a conference to engage in their scientific committee?
- What qualifications should one have for that?
- Is it normal to apply for this by email online? and how?

Comment: Also see [How to show interest to serve as a TPC or reviewer in top conferences?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15555/how-to-show-interest-to-serve-as-a-tpc-or-reviewer-in-top-conferences)

Comment: Well, thats close, but I am not looking for top conferences, even small ones are fine to start. @ff524

Comment: The marked duplicate, [How do you join programme committees for conferences?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/611/how-do-you-join-programme-committees-for-conferences), is not specifically about top conferences. (See especially [the second answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/624/11365) to that question, which specifically addresses your question about how an email request to be on TPC would be perceived.)